# Rails3: Change location of temp (tmp) directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, tmp

I usually develop in my local Dropbox folder. Some files in the tmp-folder get locked by the browsers (and keep Dropbox busy), Growl throws exceptions and so on.

Therefore I am looking for a configuration setting to put the tmp-folder outside the Rails-app bundle. Is that possible?

Comment: As far as there is not any configuration about your temp folder (it is more about convention, that it is `/Rails.root/tmp`). But you can try to cheat a little: remove your tmp folder out of your Rails app and create a symlink for it as an ordinary Rails `tmp` dir. I don't know if it will work :))

Comment: Symlinks are of good use to get Dropbox to sync files outside the Dropbox folder too...  :)))

Comment: ok, I've just tried :) never used Dropbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the answer you're looking for - but I can definitively say that there's no configuration option to change where Rails thinks the tmp folder is.  The location is hard coded in many different places in the Rails codebase.

Looks like the symlink **will** sync the original file, so you'll probably have the same locking problems.

**If you do**, then you can just use the symlinks the other way around to solve your problem, ie. create your project **outside** your dropbox, and symlink everything other than `tmp` into a folder in your dropbox.

So you might have your Rails app in `~/work/rails_project/<all the rails dirs including tmp>` and then you'll have a corresponding dir in your dropbox, like `~/dropbox/rails_project` and then **inside** that dir you'll manually create a bunch of symlinks and then delete the `tmp` one, using bash you'd do this:

```
$ for f in ~/work/rails_project/*; do ln -s $f; done
$ rm tmp
```

You'd need to remember to run that again if you ever added a new file/directory to the root of your app.

Comment: Right you are...that is a creative solution. Thanks for the clarification that there is no configuration option!

Answer (score 5):

```
ENV['TMPDIR'] = Rails.root.join('tmp')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I did not succeed with `ENV['TMPDIR'] = '/tmp'`, no matter where I put this line, neither config files nor initializer. Could you please expand your answer?

Comment: try to put
ENV['TMPDIR'] = Rails.root.join('tmp').to_s 
at your environment.rb file

Answer (score 2):

you can't change tmp directory, but you can configure tmp cache directory.

```
# config/application.rb
config.cache_store                   = [ :file_store, "/tmp/rails-cache/" ]
config.assets.cache_store            = [ :file_store, "/tmp/rails-cache/assets/#{Rails.env}/" ]
```

you can read more at [configuration.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/configuration.rb)

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude a directory from being synced in Dropbox by using **Selective Sync**: http://www.dropbox.com/help/175/en

Basically select the Dropbox preferences and go in Advanced. Select then Selective Sync and look for the folder that you want to exclude from syncing [there is also an advanced view if you have to go in a deeper than 1st level dir depth]