# How can I change temporary directory (Rails.root+"tmp") of rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to install rails to a read only directory.

**SQLite** database file paths are configured in **database.yml**, but I can not find a way of setting the temporary directory for Rails.

Comment: It might not be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708213/rails3-change-location-of-temp-tmp-directory

Comment: Thanks. I hope some enhancement in the future.